# PDO json_encode does not work, where is the error?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I'm trying this for the first time, so my code comes entirely from tutorials but it just doesn't work.
I run **PHP 7** with **JSON 1.4.0** enabled.

I can print the resulting rows if I don't use json_encode, so my connection and the query are OK.

Error reporting is active but doesn't output anything either.

If I run the php file on my server, I just get a blank page.

Here's my code:

```
error_reporting(-1);

try {
    $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=server.com;dbname=theDB",username,password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table');
    $stmt->execute();

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));



} catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to your code or look in your error logs.

Comment: @bub the `-1` in PHP turns on [all PHP errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), but they may not be displayed.

Comment: you're setting the exception mode AFTER you attempt the connection. by default pdo doesn't throw exceptions, so if the connection fails, it won't throw an exception, because exceptions haven't been enabled yet.

Comment: Uh @MarcB, setting those attributes like that [is correct](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), no? Having the query execution code in the same try statement is less than desirable, but if the connection fails it should throw the error.

Comment: Add [`echo  json_last_error_msg();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) at the end. Add `;charset=utf-8` in the PDO connection string.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: d'oh. right... I need to go get some coffee.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank heavens for that, I just had to go and run a test to prove it. Mark frightened the bejazus out if me

Comment: I'm only on my third cup @MarcB!

Comment: Thanks @trincot, now I get this error: "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set in /home/.sites/123/site7948827/web/bedauerlicher_fetcher.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /home/.sites/123/site7948827/web/bedauerlicher_fetcher.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', 'username', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in /home/.sites/123/site7948827/web/bedauerlicher_fetcher.php on line 8

Comment: It skeered me when I saw it @RiggsFolly! Thank goodness for coffee!

Comment: What did you chnage to get that error? Because it looks like you removed the `try {} catch {}` block

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added `echo json_last_error_msg();` at the end of the file and `;charset=utf-8` at the end of the PDO string

Comment: Add UTF-8 like this `$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=server.com;dbname=theDB;charset=UTF8",username,password);` in the DSN

Comment: @RiggsFolly YES! A GOD AMONGST CODERS! `charset=UTF8` instead of `charset=utf-8` did the trick! I'm getting my JSON object now! :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do you hear that everyone, Just goes to show how wrong one developer can be about another!  hahhhaha I can beat my chest and Holla like Tarzan too, on a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION: (Thanks @trincot & @RiggsFolly)**
I had to change this line

```
$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=server.com;dbname=theDB",username,password);
```

to

```
$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=server.com;dbname=theDB;charset=UTF8",username,password);`
```

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode()` will not throw an exception on error, you have to [verify the result yourself](http://php.net/json_last_error):

```
if (json_last_error()!==JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
    exit;
}
```

Almost everytime this question comes here it's `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded